# Windows 10: aws working in powershell but not cmd?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell

Hi I'm on windows 10 and trying to run a basic aws command.

```
aws s3 ls target --profile user1
```

I have a already configure this profile and I can see it in the directory.  This works when I'm in powershell but not cmd.  In cmd I get this

```
The config profile (user1;) could not be found
```

is there anything I can do? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a already configure this profile"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a profile first.

example:

```
aws configure --profile user1
```

Here is a link that can help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-profiles

Comment: I did that; however strange thing is that it only works when I'm in powershell but not cmd.